# deploy different spring boot wars on external tomcat with same port

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, tomcat8

how do I deploy different  spring boot wars on tomcat container
I have 3 wars with name

myapp1.war

myapp2.war

myapp3.war

I have added these wars into tomcat webapps folder and did some changes in server.xml under <Host? tag.

```
<Context path="/apipath" docBase="myapp1" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

I can access the application on http://localhost:9080/apipath/mymethoduriapp1
Now if I put another Context path in same host tag for other war like

```
<Context path="/apipath" docBase="myapp2" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

server unable to start now.

is there any way that we can have multiple context path so I can access all application on same port.
example.

http://localhost:9080/apipath/mymethoduriapp1

http://localhost:9080/apipath/mymethoduriapp2

http://localhost:9080/apipath/mymethoduriapp3

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: If you do not add a docbase, it will automatically consider all wars in webapp folder and deploy them.

Comment: thank you for your response, Agree it is now considering web app folder but path taking as wars name not from context path as specified above /apipath

Answer (score -1):

> No you can't have multiple apps listening on the same port. How would
> the kernel know which application to send the packages to? What you
> can do that run a http server such nginx or apache  which gonna listen
> on 9090 and each app in a different port and then proxy the requests
> based on the URL to the desired app.
>
> nginx is probably the most popular and easier to setup , Below shows
> the basic configuration for this case

[Nginx Reverse Proxy. Multiple Applications on One Domain](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/nginx-reverse-proxy.html)